# "Is too" instead of "it is"

Tags: conversation

The following is a dialogue of an animated movie (A bug's life), I don't understand why one of them says "Is too" instead of saying "it is". Is a this a natural way of responding and insisting on what you're implying?

> -Oh, being little's not such a bad thing.
>   +Yes, it is.
>   -No, it's not.
>   +Is too!
>   -Is not.
>   +Is too.
>   -Is not.
>   +Is too.

Comment: It's a duplicate, if I remember it right. Please check previous posts.

Comment: It's teen lingo/ kid lingo, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

These forms of contradictory retort (often heard from children)...

> "it is [so] too"
>
> "but it is"
>
> "it is but"

...seem to have a "but" or "too" therein for emphasis. It might not have Germanic routes but it brought to mind [aber](http://llt.msu.edu/vol5num3/mollering/default.html) in German for me, which in particulate form sometimes serves as a sort of surprise or emphasis (link provided for some clarity on this if interest arises - sorry it's not entirely committal *emphasis*, but I've heard as much from speakers). Of course "is too" also could be roughly compared with *in truth* and *indeed* in English; more emphasis.

I'm not sure how this form of 'argumentative' emphasis became a cliched juvenile retort - like anything and everything, perhaps through meme and repetition. Then, once denoted as a children's mode of speech it no doubt lost favour (and rhetorical credibility) among adults.